# How to display multiple database rows in an image

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to display multiple fields in 1 image using imagettftext(), I am retrieving the data from a MySQL database, but I just can't seem to get it to work the way I need it to. I need it to display a different field in a different area of the image.

So far I have tried while and foreach.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $username = $row['PLAYER_NAME'];
}
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, 25, 52, $text_color, $font, $username);
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, 25, 138, $text_color, $font, $username);
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, 25, 229, $text_color, $font, $username);
```

That currently outputs:
Field1
Field1
Field1

On the image.

Instead I would like it to display Field1, Field2 and Field3. Is that possible? If so, just sending me in the right direction would be a huge help.

I have been experimenting with this for about 3 days now, but have had no luck.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you're asking. You're only retrieving `$username` from the database, and then adding it to the image three times. If you want to add other fields, then all you need to do is retrieve them inside your while loop, and amend the calls to `imagettftext()` to use those fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$username` is the same on each function call, so you will obviously get the same text each time.  Perhpas you should consider reading the DB data into an array like this:

```
$usernames = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $usernames[] = $row['PLAYER_NAME'];
}
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, 25, 52, $text_color, $font, $usernames[0]);
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, 25, 138, $text_color, $font, $usernames[1]);
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, 25, 229, $text_color, $font, $usernames[2]);
```